# Using a non-static UserControl without using as an object

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

This question is going to be worded awkwardly as I'm finding it difficult to word it. My code is also a bit of a mess as I'm still learning C# and probably shouldn't have delved right into WPF. This may also be why I haven't found the solution with google. Anyway...

My program has a menu with a search bar, with a tab-control that separates the program into sections and each tab-item has a user-control. The user-controls are being used to keep the XAML of the main window clean. This caused the problem where I couldn't use the search bar because it was separate from the UserControl.

As the methods in the user-control can't be static, I can only think to create it using ClassName title `GetItem newItem = new GetItem()`. This works! Except for the fact that nothing will be displayed on the user-control (whereas MessageBox shows me that the data exists) because (I think) I've pretty much created a new user-control to what I am displaying on the program using XAML with `<local:user-control>`.

I'm not familiar with data binding too much, but I've tried with no success to bind the labels, because I was under the impression that by using binds, the labels will both show the same data. Is this the case and I just implemented it wrong?

Also, I imagine that by removing the the user-control being shown using XAML and instead displaying programmatically after creating it as an object would work, but I would prefer alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to get the effect I'm hoping to achieve was this.

While I added: `<local:UserControl/>`, 
I just needed to add `x:Name="InstanceName"` to get:

```
 <local:UserControl x:Name="InstanceName"/>
```

With this, I can replace `GetItem newItem = new GetItem();` with:

```
 InstanceName.GetMethod();
```